# Propagate errors to parent resolver in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, resolver

Hi everyone I have an issue in my schema + resolver implementation.
The as is situation is:

A schema like this

```
"User Response either success or failure"
union UserResponse = UserSuccessfulResponse | GenericResponse

type UserSuccessfulResponse {
  "Set true false for the response of the API"
  success: Boolean!
  "User Info"
  userInfo: User
  "Currency Info"
  currency: Currency!
}

type User {
  userId: String!
}

type Currency {
  currencySymbol: String!
}

type Query {
  "Get User Info"
  getUser: UserResponse!
}
```

And a resolver like this:

```
Query: {
getUser: async (_, __, context) => {
          try {
            return await (context.datasourceApiMap[AccountAPI.apiName] as AccountAPI).getUser()
          } catch (error: any) {
            return {
              success: false,
              errorCode: error.extensions?.code ?? "USER_NOT_FOUND",
              errorMessage: error.message,
            }
          }
        },
      }
....

UserResponse: {
        __resolveType(response) {
          if (response.success) {
            return "UserSuccessfulResponse"
          }
          if (!response.success) {
            return "GenericResponse"
          }
          return null
        },
      },
```

where the *getUser* function in the datasource is returning a UserResponse or throwing an error that I handle in the catch clause.

```
public abstract getUser(): Promise<UserResponse>
```

This API call contains two different calls to REST APIs:

- one to retrieve the user information
- one to retrieve the currency information

This is terribly wrong! If the client (frontend in my case) only require either the user information in the schema or the currency we still call the two APIs, reducing performances and leveraging the power of GraphQL resolvers.

What then I tried to do was to create a resolver for the UserSuccessfulResponse:

```
UserSuccessfulResponse: {
        userInfo: async (_, __, context) => {
          return await (context.datasourceApiMap[AccountAPI.apiName] as AccountAPI).getUserInfo()
        },
        currency: async (_, __, context) => {
          return await (context.datasourceApiMap[AccountAPI.apiName] as AccountAPI).getCurrency()
        },
      }
```

that calls two different datasources to resolve user or currency information.

```
public abstract getUserInfo(): Promise<User>
public abstract getCurrency(): Promise<Currency>
```

The getUser resolver would become something like:

```
getUser: async (_, __, context) => {
          try {
            return {
            success: true,
            userInfo: this.getResolvers().UserSuccessfulResponse?.userInfo,
            currency: this.getResolvers().UserSuccessfulResponse?.currency,
          }
          } catch (error: any) {
            return {
              success: false,
              errorCode: error.extensions?.code ?? "USER_NOT_FOUND",
              errorMessage: error.message,
            }
          }
        },
```

The point is that in this way if one of the two calls fails I'm not able to catch the error anymore as it is not thrown and propagated to the parent resolver anymore (I was expecting UserSuccessfulResponse resolver to propagate the error to the getUser resolver, but it's clearly not).

I can't set the *success* field to true or false anymore, accordingly to the presence or not of an error.

I don't know how to solve this issue. Frontend is already implemented and I can't change the schema anymore without a lot of pain.

How can I still split the resolver in two different calls without affecting the schema? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: IMO you're kind of stuck with this problem given that "success" in your `UserSuccessfulResponse` type covers the two API calls. I would @deprecate that whole type and gradually move your clients over to a better structure. The parent resolver is fire-and-forget. Once it runs the child resolvers run but the parent resolver doesn't have an error handler for errors thrown by its children.

Comment: indeed I wanted to understand if it was possible to do it in some way, but I didn't find any other way to do it. So I think the solution is to remove the successful field and handle the error in another way.

Comment: ps. I would ask your front-end team how often this query is made. It looks like the kind of query one runs at login to establish the user's identity and get basic application setup info (ex: the user's currency). It's unusual to create a special type for this however since multiple GraphQL queries can be run [simultaneously](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/multiple-queries-in-a-single-graphql-request)

Comment: it's indeed a query used at login, as you perfectly described. And in this moment both information (user and currency) are retrieved in the same query. Even tho, I feel like I did something wrong putting the two REST calls together without any split. But I do get your point. I will discuss and maybe deprecate and split the two calls in the future. I think the best is to get rid of the _success_ field and handle the errors differently.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you implement two queries, `getUser` and `getCurrency` and that the front-end gang these together in a single network request.

```
query startMeUp {
  getUser {
    …user fields
  }
  getCurrency {
    …currency fields
  }
}
```

Each query could hit one of your back-end APIs and report standard GraphQL errors.